# Calling C# code from JavaScript in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint

Ok here's what I'm trying to do.

I have this custom action (button on my SharePoint-ribbon). This should call a Javascript, which in turn should call a C#-code.

I have the following:

```
<CustomAction
Id="Ribbon.Documents.DocsetZip"
Title="Download Document Set as ZIP"
RegistrationType="ContentType"
RegistrationId="0x0120D520"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
>
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition
      Location="Ribbon.Documents.Share.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.Document.Share.DownasZip"
                        Sequence="20"
                        Command="Ribbon.ManageDocumentSet.MDS.Manage.DownZip"
                        Alt="Download as ZIP"
                        Image16by16="/_layouts/images/zipfile16x.png"
                        Image32by32="/_layouts/images/zipfile32x.png"
                        LabelText="Download as ZIP file"
        ToolTipTitle="Download as ZIP file"
        ToolTipDescription="Compress the document set and download"
        TemplateAlias="o1"/>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="Ribbon.ManageDocumentSet.MDS.Manage.DownZip"
      CommandAction="javascript:__doPostBack('DownloadZipDelegateEvent', '')" />
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

And i have a class:

```
public class MyRibbonDelegateClass : WebControl
{

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.EnsureChildControls();
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (this.Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "DownloadZipDelegateEvent")
        {
            using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("C:\\temp\\perl.txt"))
            {
                //
                // Write one line.
                //
                writer.WriteLine("First line");
                //
                // Write two strings.
                //
                writer.Write("A ");
                writer.Write("B ");
                //
                // Write the default newline.
                //
                writer.Write(writer.NewLine);
            }

        }
    }
```

It seems my code gets executed, but I cannot find my file anywhere.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it as follows :

```
function getOutlook() {
    var xmlHttpReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpReq.open("GET", _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/SendDocuments/MyCustomHandler.ashx?ItemsArray=" + fileRefArray, false);
        xmlHttpReq.send(null);
}

function createXMLHttpRequest() {
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch (e) { }
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) { }
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) { }
    alert("XMLHttpRequest not supported");
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use __DoPostback to invoke a server side hit from javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ServerPostWithParameter(parameter)
{
  __doPostBack('btnSave', parameter)
 }
</script>
```

in server side,

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // this is your parameters 
  // Request["__EVENTTARGET"]; // this is your button
}
```

Comment: but i'm actually supposed to call the C# from a click on a button which i'm adding myself to the ribbon of SharePoint. So not from a page I made myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an HttpHandler with your server-side code and call it with parameters from JavaScript.

E.g. create an ~sitecollection/_layouts/15/MyCustomHandler.ashx and call it from JavaScript like this (SharePoint 2013 uses virtual path to layouts directory as '_layouts/15', SharePoint 2010 -- just '_layouts'):

```
$.get(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + '/_layouts/15/MyCustomHandler.ashx?Param1=Value1&Param2=Value2');
```

Comment: How can I make sure the ashx gets deployed? For some reason, it doesn't get deployed.And the deploymenttype is set to NoDeployment. How can I change that?

Comment: Ok i found this article : OK, I used this to deploy it : http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/adding-and-deploying-generic-handlers-ashx-to-a-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-project/
But I still don't have my code running.

Comment: I have this in my js-file : 
function SendSingleDoc(ListId, ItemId) {
    var sdList;
    try {
        get(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + '/_layouts/SendDocuments/MyCustomHandler.ashx');
    }
}But I keep getting an error: '$' is undefined

Comment: You need to add a link to jQuery.js file somewhere in your code: